# Mapping value objects from third party libraries

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity I need to persist to a relational DB via Hibernate **annotations**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fizzes")
public class Fizz {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="fizz_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="fizz_wooz")
    private String wooz;

    // ??? here I am unsure!
    private Buzz buzz;

    // Constructor, getters/setters down here, etc...
}

public class Buzz {
    private int jupiter;

    private String neptune;

    // Constructor, getters/setters down here, etc...
}
```

The problem with `Buzz` is:

- I do **not** want it to be its own entity/table. I want it to be a "value object/type" that gets mapped to the `fizzes` table (by way of adding columns to it)
- `Buzz` is from a third party library and hence I can't modify it

Hence the final result, in table form, that I'm looking for is:

```
[fizzes] table
==============
fizz_id, PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
fizz_wooz, NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
fizz_buzz_jupiter, INT NOT NULL
fizz_buzz_neptune, NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

How can I get Hibernate to do this annotation-based mapping when I can't modify `Buzz`?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke - yes I don't have source code and don't want to violate any licensing for making modifications to the classes. As for why I desired annotations over mapping file, I just prefer annotations because they are cleaner (IMHO). Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are searching for is called `Embeddable`.

```
@Entity
public class Fizz {
    ...

    @Embedded
    private Buzz buzz;

}
```

And you can define a *mapping file* just for `Buzz`:

```
<entity-mappings version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm    
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd">
    <embeddable class="...Buzz">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="jupiter"><column name="fizz_buzz_jupiter"/></basic>
            <basic name="neptune"><column name="fizz_buzz_neptune"/></basic>
        </attributes>
    </embeddable>
</entity-mappings>
```

You can include that mapping file in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence-unit>
    <mapping-file>.../orm.xml</mapping-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

If you really want to use annotations for `Buzz`: You can't define annotations for other classes. Thats the meaning of annotations: they are *inline* and belong to their class. Otherwise there would be no benefit compared to mapping files...

But you could extend `Buzz` and use that one with *property access*:

```
@Entity
public class Fizz {
    ...

    @Embedded
    private BuzzExtension buzz;

}

@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class BuzzExtension extends Buzz {
    @Column(name="fizz_buzz_jupiter")
    public int getJupiter() {
        return super.getJupiter();
    }

    @Column(name="fizz_buzz_neptune")
    public String getNeptune() {
        return super.getNeptune();
    }

}
```

Only drawback: You can't use instances of `Buzz` in `Fizz`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Tobias Liefke (+1 and green check)!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the properites of `Buzz` object to be present in the `Fizz` object which means both the properties of `Buzz` and `Fizz` should be present as columns in the same table `fizzes`.

So you have to extend the `Fizz` object where the `Buzz` will be annotated as `@MappedSuperClass`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fizzes")
public class Fizz extends Buzz {
    // Fizz properties
    // No need to add Buzz as a field
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class Buzz {
    // Buzz properties
}
```

If you do not add `@MappedSuperclass` annotation, then you cannot achieve this. Even though `Buzz` is extended by `Fizz`, fields of `Buzz` will not be recognized by Hibernate as Hibernate do only reflection on the fields present in the `Fizz` but not on the fields present in extended `Buzz` class, unless you specify `@MappedSuperclass` annotation. MappedSuperclass will tell the hibernate to also use reflection on the fields of `Buzz` object.

Comment: Thanks @user1354678 (+1) - however, **I can't modify `Buzz` source!!!** In other words, I can't add `@MappedSuperclass`...ideas?

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys, I've updated my answer. I have not tried without `@MappedSuperclass` annotation. I guess the working way of hibernate is what I've explained in the last. Maybe you try without `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

Comment: Thanks again @user1354678, but are you *really* saying that Hibernate can't OR/M classes created/owned by 3rd parties? For instance, if some 3rd party JAR off Maven Central contains some classes that I want persisted as value objects/types, you're telling me there's no way to do this without modifying their source to contain `@MappedSuperclass`?!?! If that's true, then I'm just completely *thunderstruck*!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys, I say you can use the fields of the thrid party as an child table by defining it as a field in the parent class, but you cannot when you use that thrid party class by extending it in the parent class. Like I said earlier, I have not tried without `@MappedSuperclass` annotation, maybe you can try that but i assume the result will no reflection for that fields. Looks like it's possible with `@Embedded` annotation

Comment: @user1354678: You missed the concepts of `Embeddable`. To use a `MappedSuperclass` just to have the properties in the same table would lead to a bad class design.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke, thanks for the info.. I didn't even used / heard about `Embedded` until now.. Maybe it'll help me at certain cases..