# Hibernate Inheritance. super class attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-inheritance

I need to map a class to which I have no access.

```
@Entity
public class User extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private Integer age;
    ...
}
```

My tables are auto-generated and It only generate the columns at the subclass, how can I map the super class if I don't have access to annotate it with `@Inheritance`?

I tried with `@AttributeOverrides(value = { @AttributeOverride( name = "username", column = @Column(name = "username")) })` but doesn't looks to work

Comment: if you don't have access to annotate the superclass with @Inheritance? you can use mapping via xml

Comment: I was looking [strategy kinds](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html) and all of then requires create to tables. There isn't something that just mapped it like a unique class? because in this case, maybe is better just copy&paste de superclass and add my properties instead extend it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping value objects from third party libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164244/mapping-value-objects-from-third-party-libraries)

Answer (score 3):

**I think the most convinient solution here is property access.** Just add a few overriding getters and annotate them:

```
@Column("username")
public String getUsername(){
   return super.getUsername();
}
```